# How to create tar.gz file using apache beam

Tags: java, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, google-dataflow

I used the below to create a `tar.gz` file, and `.gz` file was created but tar file was not available.  How to achieve the result?

```java
PCollection<String> lines = pipeline.apply("To read from file",
    TextIO.read().from(<file path>));

lines.apply(TextIO.write()
    .to("C:\\Ddrive\\saveAllRequest1.txt")
    .withCompression(Compression.GZIP);
```

and how to tar multiple files.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `tar` file is an inherently non-parallel operation. One option here is to use the [Wait](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html) transform after your write with a DoFn that manually creates the tarball.

Comment: It would be very useful if you share the sample code for the same